# mongodb update with many embedd document

Tags: mongodb, updates, mongodb-.net-driver

guys, I use official CSharp Driver of mongodb,  I got these two classes:

```
public class A
{
    public A()
    {
        Bs = new List<B>();
    }

    [BsonId]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<B> Bs { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

in db, B is embedd in A document, entity is an object of A, then do the saving job like this:

```
collection.Save<A>(entity);
```

the Save method will perform either insert or update depends on the Id, my question is: when i do collection.Save(entity) the second time, that means entity document already exists in the A collection,  does every fields in A and B document got updated?  I dont know how the driver handler this kind of thing.  supposed there ara a lot of B objects, let say 100 of them and not modified.  what process going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `Save`, base on your `[BsonId]` field driver decides what to do with this document:

- if document with `Id` does not exist in collection, it will `insert` this document
- if document with `Id` exists in collection, it will `update` this document (based on your `Id`). Update means it will replace all fields with the new fields from your `entity`

Here is an example how `save` method works in pseudocode (the same as in C# driver):

```
   function save( doc ) {
      if( doc["_id"] ) {
         update( {_id: doc["_id"] }, doc, { upsert: true } );
      }
      else {
         insert(doc);
      }
   }
```

Comment: thanks for your patient anwser, I think the sentence: "Update means it will replace all fields with the new fields from your entity" is something valuable, in that way, all fields in B objects will got replaced, that B number maybe huge.  I 'm looking for the solution like this: when calling collection.Save<A>(entity) method, B document will update when the corresponding object is modified, otherwise, don't do the "all replacing things".

Comment: I can suggest you to:
1) calculate the hash of your `B` field and store it in your document. 2) before saving, get your document by `Id`
3) If not exists - just insert.
4) If exists, calculate the hash of your `entity.B` field and compare with existing document hash
5) If hashes are the same - do nothing. If different - Save this document

Comment: You might look at doing an update with an upsert=true and specifying the B's as a $addToSet . $addToSet takes each element of an array and adds it to the target array field only if doesn't already exist.